# Ruby On Rails - How Can I Update A Model Record Using Output from a form_for Outside of Its Normal Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2.11 application where I have a contact form in my view named contact that just sent an email.  The logic was working well.  Now we have decided that we want to save the contents of the form to a ReceivedEmail model using a PostgreSQL database.

I changed my form_tag form to a form_for @received_email form.  Here is my form_for view:

```
<%= form_for(@received_email) do |f| %>
  <p class="radio-buttons">
    <span class="label1"><%= f.label "Select one: (required)" %></span>
    <%= f.radio_button :purpose, '1' %><span class="label2"><%= f.label :purpose_order, 'My Order' %></span>
    <%= f.radio_button :purpose, '2' %><span class="label3"><%= f.label :purpose_special, 'Quote For Special Order' %></span>
    <%= f.radio_button :purpose, '3' %><span class="label4"><%= f.label :purpose_wholesale, 'Wholesale Discounts' %></span>
    <%= f.radio_button :purpose, '4' %><span class="label5"><%= f.label :purpose_church, 'Store/Church Discounts' %></span>
    <%= f.radio_button :purpose, '5' %><span class="label6"><%= f.label :purpose_other, 'General Inquiry' %></span>
  </p><br><br>
  <%= f.label "First Name (required)" %><%= f.text_field :first_name, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "First Name (max. 30)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Last Name (required)" %><%= f.text_field :last_name, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "Last Name (max. 30)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Email (required)" %><%= f.text_field :email, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 60, placeholder: "Valid Email Address (max. 60)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Order Number" %><%= f.text_field :order, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 20, placeholder: "Order #  (max. 20)" %><span class="contact-required">Required for My Order</span><br>
  <%= f.label "Business / Organization" %><%= f.text_field :company, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "Business/Organization Name (max. 30)" %><span class="contact-required">Required for Wholesale Discounts & Store/Church Discounts</span><br>
  <%= f.label "Business / Organization Website" %><%= f.text_field :website, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 70, placeholder: "Company Website (max. 70)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "More Info About You" %><%= f.text_area :about_you, :minlength => 10, :maxlength => 255, placeholder: "More Info About You and/or Your Organization (max. 255.)" %>
  <span class="contact-required">Required for Wholesale Discounts & Store/Church Discounts</span><br>
  <%= f.label "Address (required)" %><%= f.text_field :address, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 50, placeholder: "Street Address (max. 50)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "City (required)" %><%= f.text_field :city, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "City (max. 30)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "State (required)" %><%= f.text_field :state, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "State/Province (max. 30)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Postal Code / Zip (required)" %><%= f.text_field :zip, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 15, placeholder: "Postal/Zip (max. 15)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Country (required)" %><%= f.text_field :country, :minlength => 2, :maxlength => 30, placeholder: "Country (max. 30)" %><br>
  <%= f.label "Message (required)" %><%= f.text_area :message, :minlength => 10, :maxlength => 255, placeholder: "Message or Project Information (max. 255)" %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The next thing I did was to make minor changes to my controller code:

```
if params[:commit]=='Submit'
  if params[:first_name].blank? || params[:last_name].blank? || params[:address].blank? || params[:city].blank? || params[:state].blank? || params[:zip].blank? || params[:country].blank? || 
     params[:message].blank? || params[:purpose].blank? || params[:email].blank? || params[:email] !~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[\w\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    flash.now[:error] = "First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, Address, City, State, Postal Code / Zip, Country and Message are required for all emails.  You must also select an email type."
    render 'contact'
  elsif params[:purpose] == '1' && params[:order].blank?
    flash.now[:error] = "Order Number is required when selecting My Order."
    render 'contact'
  elsif (params[:purpose] == '3' || params[:purpose] == '4') && (params[:company].blank? || params[:about_you].blank?)
    flash.now[:error] = "Business / Organization and More Info About You are required when selecting Wholesale Discounts or Store/Church Discounts."
    render 'contact'
  else
    @received_email = ReceivedEmail.new(params[:received_email])
    if @received_email.save
      begin
        HyperCubeOfLoveMailer.inquiry_email(@received_email).deliver
        flash.now[:success] = "The HyperCube Of Love Team has received your inquiry.  You should receive a confirmation email shortly."
      rescue Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPAuthenticationError => pages_error
        logger.warn pages_error
        flash.now[:notice] = "There was a problem with sending your inquiry to the HyperCube Of Love Team.  Please resubmit your inquiry."
      end   
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      render 'contact'
    end
  end
else
  render 'contact'
end
```

I added :received_emails to config.rb because the first time I tried to execute this code I got an error stating that a route related to the model did not exist.

The next time I tried to execute this code to create the ReceiveEmail record I got an initialize error because it was looking for received_emails_controller.rb.

I then created the controller with a new view.  After attempting to execute this I ended up with an error stating that I did not have a create view.  Then I created the create view.  I just created it to see where I ended up.  It displayed my create view.  I KNOW I SHOULD NOT HAVE HAD TO DO THIS STUFF.

The only database access for now will be to add a record for this form.  All I need is to move the data from my form to the record and add it to the model.

I did some checking of Rails commands.  I believe I could do something like this for all the fields on my form to create the records:

```
ReceiveModel.create(purpose: params[:purpose], first_name: params[:first_name], etc.)
```

However I thought that maybe I could do an insert of some kind using params[:received_email] somehow but I do not know how to do that or if this is possible.

```
ReceiveModel.create(params[:received_email])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the structure already in your controller code is the correct way to approach things:

```
@received_email = ReceivedEmail.new(params[:received_email])
if @received_email.save
  # Send the e-mail 
else
  # Re-show the page because something didn't work
end
```

However, since 90% of what you want to do is supported by the Rails scaffolding, you might want to start fresh with a `rails generate scaffold ContactMessage purpose:integer first_name:string ...`. That will give you all code to create and review contact messages. Then you can replace the generated _form.html.erb with your own form, and put your notification e-mail code in the ContactMessageController.

Comment: Normally I use the Rails processing for database maintenance when I need to add, change, delete or view records.  All I want to do is add a record that I will rarely if ever look at.  I already have working code that I wanted to make a few modifications to in order to create the record from the form data.  If possible I do not want to rewrite my code and create another controller, especially since all I want to do is add a record.  I am asking about exception code that I probably will not use in another application.

Comment: Ok. As far as I can tell, the code in your controller should be doing what you want (loading its member values from the form). Does that not seem to be happening?

Comment: Dan, it was not working because it expected my code for the model to be in a second controller which I was trying to avoid creating.  I have decided to take your suggestion and create a second controller for this even though it did not directly answer my question.  The purpose of adding the model is for legal purposes if we were challenged about a matter.  Doing the second controller will begin the process of being able to access the email data if needed.  The contact form will be the new method.  I will code the other methods later.